# How to NOT resolve paths with Webpack?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, require

I'm working on a ReactJs project with Webpack and *sass-loader*, *css-loader* & *url-loader*.

I would like **to not resolve** the font-face paths and keep it exactly how it was set in the SASS file.

#### The issue:

If I call an absolute path (ie: `http://fonts.com/my-font.eot` or `/path/to/my-font.eot`), the path is not resolved.

However, if I use a relative path (ie: `my-font.eot` or `path/to/my-font.eot`), *url-loader* tries to resolve the path.

In my case, I need to use a relative path (even if it generates a 404 error).

#### What I tried:

I tried to exclude all font extensions in the *url-loader*, but Webpack doesn't know what to do with this type of file even if the file potentially doesn't exist.

Here the error I get:

> Module parse failed: C:....\fonts\my-font.eot Unexpected character '
>   ' (1:1) You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.

I also tried to disable the "url" option of css-loader, but absolutely nothing happens. I guess it is highly possible that I didn't add the option correctly:

```
{
    test: /\.scss$/,
    loaders: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader"],
    options: { url: false }
},
```

Here is what my current code looks like :

```
module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        exclude: [
          /\.html$/,
          /\.(js|jsx)$/,
          /\.css$/,
          /\.scss$/,
          /\.json$/,
          /\.svg$/
        ],
        loader: 'url',
        query: {
          limit: 10000,
          name: 'path/dist/[name].[hash:8].[ext]'
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loaders: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader"]
      },
      ...
    ]
  },
  ...
}
```

Comment: Maybe I'm confused on your purpose, but have you tried not requiring them? I mean, if you just don't want webpack to use them, just don't require them

Comment: @Mese Actually, I don't want to "require" them. The thing is that all `url(...)` in CSS files are automatically required by css-loader and url-loader. So, the question is, how I do not require them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I wasn't adding the *css-loader* option properly.

Because I didn't find a way to add options directly using the array syntax, I had to switch to the string syntax.

This code doesn't work:

```
{
    test: /\.scss$/,
    loaders: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader"],
    options: { url: false }
},
```

This code works:

```
{
    test: /\.scss$/,
    loader: 'style!css?url=false!sass'
}
```

Comment: Validate your own answer for people that come after :)

Answer (score 5):

This question might be a little old, but I still want to correct the answer.

When you want to use the array syntax, you basically define all the options for every single loader. In order to do so you have to use an object for  the loader in the array. So instead of

```
{
    test: /\.scss$/,
    loaders: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader"],
    options: { url: false }
},
```

You have to write

```
{
    test: /\.scss$/,
    loaders: [
         "style-loader", 
         {
            loader:'css-loader',
            options: {
                 url: false
            }
         },
         "sass-loader"],

},
```

Answer (score 1):

I needed a different solution than the accepted one:

```css
  /* webpackIgnore: true */
  background: url('/api/assets/?image=background.webp');
```

Did the trick. In my case, I wanted to skip resolving a path that I want to resolve by calling the backend, so it has to stay like this and should not be resolved by Webpack.

I found this comment syntax `/* webpackIgnore: true */` from the [Webpack documentation](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/css-loader/#disable-url-resolving-using-the--webpackignore-true--comment).

### [EDIT]

When I tried to build, the Webpack comment got stripped (I'm using Vue) by postcss & cssnano, and I had to write it this form [so the comment is preserved](https://cssnano.co/docs/optimisations/discardcomments/) and it also passes the build: **`/*! /* webpackIgnore: true */`**